# 500 Internal Server Error en archivo php

Tags: php

tengo un pequeño problema al momento de realizar la validación al parecer esta relacionado con mi archivo php y en los errores de consola me aparece el mensaje descrito en la pregunta, error 500, ahora que motivaría a este error algún punto y coma mal colocado, algún bloque de código mal implementado?.
Cabe recalcar que estoy haciendo pruebas de manera local haciendo uso de mamp y al momento la respectiva  validación consigo ese error que no me deja cantar victoria, creería yo que todo se encuentra bien pero lamentablemente al momento de ver la consola consigo el mismo error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$("#formulariocleq").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();//almacena los datos sin refrescar
    enviar();
});
// function enviar(){
//     console.log("enviado");
// }
function enviar(){
     var datos = $("#formulariocleq").serialize();//toma los datos "nombre" y los lleva a un arreglo
     console.log(datos);
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "send_form_email.php",
         data : datos,         
         success: function(texto){
             console.log(texto)
             if(texto.trim()==="exito"){
                 correcto();
             }else{
                 phperror(texto);
             }
         }
     });
 }

 function correcto(){
     $("#mensajeexito").removeClass("d-none");
     $("#mensajeerror").addClass("d-none");
 }

 function phperror(texto){
     $("#mensajeerror").removeClass("d-none");
     $("#mensajeerror").html(texto);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../img/web/ico_dientes_sanos.ico">

    <title>Clínica Dental Equilibrium</title>
</head>

<body>

            <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <!--Grid column-->
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mb-4">
            <!--Form with header-->
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <!--Header-->
                <div class="form-header blue accent-1">
                  <h3><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>Contáctanos:</h3>
                </div>
                <p class="text-justify">Te invitamos a contáctarnos, te responderemos a la brevedad posible,un abrazo
                  <b>clinicaequilibrium.cl</b>
                </p>
                <p class="text-justify text-danger small">*Todos los campos son obligatorios</b>
                </p>
                <div class="alert alert-success d-none" id="mensajeexito">Mensaje Enviado Con Exito</div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger d-none" id="mensajeerror"></div>
                <br>
                <!--Body-->
                <form id="formulariocleq" >
                  <div class="md-form">
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre(S):</label>
                    <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" value="" id="nombre" class="form-control" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="md-form">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" class="form-control" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="md-form">
                    <label for="mensaje">Mensaje(S):</label>
                    <i class="fas fa-tag prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" class="form-control md-textarea" rows="5" required></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center mt-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Form with header-->
          </div>
       
        </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>




    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="formucleq.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

```
    <?php   
//echo "exito";
    $error ='';
    //VALIDANDO NOMBRE
    if(empty($_POST["nombre"]))
    {
        $error ='Ingresa un Nombre </br>';
    }
    else
    {
        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"]
        $nombre = filter_var($nombre,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
    //VALIDANDO EMAIL
    if(empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $error .='Ingresa un Email </br>';
    }
    else
    {
        $email = $_POST["email"]
        if (!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $error .='Ingresa un email Verdadero</br>';
        }
        else
        {
            $email = filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        }   
    }
    if(empty($_POST["mensaje"]))
    {
        $error .='Ingresa un Mensaje </br>';
    }
    else
    {
        $mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"]
        $mensaje = filter_var($mensaje,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }   

    //CUERPO MENSAJE
    $cuerpo = 'Nombre: '.$form_name.'\n';
    $cuerpo = 'E-mail: '.$form_email.'\n';
    $cuerpo = 'Mensaje: '.$form_Subjecto.'\n';

    //DIRECCION
    $enviarA ='carrobe90@gmail.com' ;       
    $titulo = 'Consulta Cliente(S) Clinica Equilibrium';    
                    
    if ($error =='') 
    {
        $success = mail($enviarA,$titulo,$cuerpo,'de;'.$email);         
        echo 'exito';
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo $error;
    }       
?>
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Tu pregunta puede quedar cerrada ya que en varios renglones omitiste los `;` y puede considerarse un *typo*

Comment: Ese pequeño detalle causo efectivamente el error 500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te faltan punto y comas en tu código PHP

```php
  <?php   
//echo "exito";
    $error ='';
    //VALIDANDO NOMBRE
    if(empty($_POST["nombre"]))
    {
        $error ='Ingresa un Nombre </br>';
    }
    else
    {
        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"]; // Acá
        $nombre = filter_var($nombre,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
    //VALIDANDO EMAIL
    if(empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $error .='Ingresa un Email </br>';
    }
    else
    {
        $email = $_POST["email"]; // Acá
        if (!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $error .='Ingresa un email Verdadero</br>';
        }
        else
        {
            $email = filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        }   
    }
    if(empty($_POST["mensaje"]))
    {
        $error .='Ingresa un Mensaje </br>';
    }
    else
    {
        $mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"]; // Acá
        $mensaje = filter_var($mensaje,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }   

    //CUERPO MENSAJE
    $cuerpo = 'Nombre: '.$form_name.'\n';
    $cuerpo = 'E-mail: '.$form_email.'\n';
    $cuerpo = 'Mensaje: '.$form_Subjecto.'\n';

    //DIRECCION
    $enviarA ='carrobe90@gmail.com' ;       
    $titulo = 'Consulta Cliente(S) Clinica Equilibrium';    
                    
    if ($error =='') 
    {
        $success = mail($enviarA,$titulo,$cuerpo,'de;'.$email);         
        echo 'exito';
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo $error;
    }       
?>
```

PHP es muy estricto con el tema de la syntax, al mínimo error te puede hacer un error 500

Ejemplo: si te dejas un parámetro en una función, un paréntesis, un punto y coma, esto puede ser causa de una falla de compilamiento y puede hacer un error 500

Comment: No es solo PHP sino cualquier lenguaje del cual no se respete su sintaxis